# When i am trying to get data formatted data from list(rich text) and bind it to pnp Rich text box cntrol nothing is visible

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp, reactjs, multiple-lines-of-text

When i am trying to get data formatted data from list(rich text) and bind it to pnp Rich text box cntrol nothing is visible in control, though the data is there in state.

I have tried to use below code:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import styles from './RichTextTest.module.scss';
    import { IRichTextTestProps } from './IRichTextTestProps';
    import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
    
    import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
    import { RichText } from "@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/RichText";
    import { autobind } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Utilities';
    import "@pnp/sp/webs";
    import "@pnp/sp/lists";
    import "@pnp/sp/items";
    
    export interface ISpfxPnpRichtextState {
    description: string;
    SuccessMessage: string;
    }
    
    export default class RichTextTest extends React.Component<IRichTextTestProps, ISpfxPnpRichtextState,{}> {
    constructor(props: IRichTextTestProps, state: ISpfxPnpRichtextState) {
    super(props);
    sp.setup({
    spfxContext: this.props.context
    });
    
    this.state = { SuccessMessage: '', description: '' };
    this._getDescription();
    }
    public render(): React.ReactElement {
    return (
    < RichText isEditMode={true} value={this.state.description} />
    );
    }
    
    @autoBind
    private async _getDescription() {
    const item: any = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Employee Registration").items.getById(61).get();
    
    console.log(this.state.description);
    console.log(item.Description);
    
    let dummyElement = document.createElement("DIV");
    dummyElement.innerHTML = item.Description;
    let outputText = dummyElement.innerText;
    
    this.setState({ description: outputText });
    }
    
    @autoBind
    private async _updateDescription() {
    console.log(this.state.description);
    const updatedItem = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Employee Registration").items.getById(61).update(
    {
    Description: this.state.description
    });
    this.setState({ SuccessMessage: 'Successfully saved' });
    }
    }
```